# Как получить значение из txt C#

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть очень большой файл **info.txt**

Пример файла info.txt

#UPDATE
1546;Grunt1;45000;0;1;0;1;;345246764;
1567;Grunt2;25083;0;1;0;1;;32589328593245;
1543;Grunt3;5643;0;1;0;1;;5462556;
1587;Grunt4;775454;0;1;0;1;;683763;
1534;Grunt5;126287;0;1;0;1;;219865764;

#DELETE
76;4639478935892;0;0;
543;47829838;0;1;
87;39475;1;0;
19;298598284;1;1;
34;4639478935892;0;0;

После #UPDATE идет значение, после каждой значение есть точка запятая
Как я могу получить значение из txt в переменную?
Буду благодарен за любую информацию

Желаемый результат:

```
#UPDATE
id = 1546
name = Grunt1
...
code = 345246764

#DELETE
num = 76
scode = 4639478935892
...
```

Comment: что такое `очень большой файл` и что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: ```очень большой файл``` это файл txt где то 30т. стр.  у меня не получается извлечь значению до ;;;;

Comment: 30 тысяч сток это сущая ерунда. Чтобы считать все строки используйте `File.ReadAllLines` метод, чтобы строку разбить на части, используйте метод строки `Split`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача интересная, попробуйте сами её решить, tym32167 минимально указал, что нужно использовать.

Мой вариант ниже.

[Пример онлайн.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lE2wbw) *(Заменил файл массивом)*

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        const string filePath = @"C:\Users\Jagailo\Desktop\info.txt";
        var actions = new List<ActionModel>();

        // Read file, fill out data
        ActionModel currentAction = null;
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))
        {
            if (line.StartsWith('#'))
            {
                if (currentAction != null)
                {
                    actions.Add(currentAction);
                }

                currentAction = new ActionModel(line);
            }
            else
            {
                currentAction?.EntityFields.Add(line.Split(';').SkipLast(1).ToArray());
            }
        }

        // Add last action to file outside of loop
        if (currentAction != null)
        {
            actions.Add(currentAction);
        }
    }
}

internal class ActionModel
{
    public string ActionName { get; }
    public List<string[]> EntityFields { get; }

    public ActionModel(string actionName)
    {
        ActionName = actionName;
        EntityFields = new List<string[]>();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, это то что я искал